# Show/hide grouped rows on header click Vuetify2 (v-data-table component)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/alexatiks/pen/wvwjVzd?editors=1010) of datatable with rows grouped by category. I want to expand/collapse it by group header click. Tried to replace the default rendering of a row using v-slot:item but seems it's not working.

The second way is to replace the default rendering of grouped rows using v-slot:group, but I hope should be another way.

Here's the code:

```html
<v-data-table
      dense
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key=name
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <template v-if="item.show">
          Show row
        </template>
        <template v-else>

        </template>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:group.header="{ items }">
        <td @click="expandRows(items[0])" 
            class="text-xs-right"
          >
            <strong>{{ items[0].category }}</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">22%</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">24%</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">25%</td>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Please suggest how can I solve that?

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to replace the default rendering of group headers and grouped rows using v-slot:group.

```
  <template v-slot:group="{ items, expand }">
    <tr @click="toggle(items[0].category)">
      <td  class="text-xs-right"><strong>{{ items[0].category }}</strong></td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">22%</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">24%</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">25%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" v-show="!item.hide">
      <td v-for="header in headers">
        {{ item[header.value] }}
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </template>
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexatiks/pen/abojjBJ?editors=1010)